# How to check array values exist and replace php

Tags: php, arrays

My Array:

```
Array ( [0] => Tuesday [1] => Thursday [2] => Friday [3] => Monday 
        [4] => Tuesday [5] => Monday [6] => Tuesday [7] => Wednesday 
      )
```

I want output array:

```
Array ( [0] => Tuesday_1 [1] => Thursday [2] => Friday [3] => Monday_1 
        [4] => Tuesday_2 [5] => Monday_2 [6] => Tuesday_3 [7] => Wednesday 
      )
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: "_I want ..._" is not a question. Please [edit] your question and post the code you have, this is _not_ a code writing service. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [ 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' ];

$dayCounter = array_fill_keys(array_unique($arr), 0);
$multipleOccurrences = array_filter(array_count_values($arr), fn($item) => $item > 1);

$result = array_reduce(
    $arr,
    function ($carry, $item) use (&$dayCounter, $multipleOccurrences) {
      if (array_key_exists($item, $multipleOccurrences)) {
        $dayCounter[$item] += 1;
        return [ ...$carry, $item . '_' . $dayCounter[$item] ];
      } else {
        return [ ...$carry, $item ];
      }
    },
    []
);
```